Cannot create a new Angular application
I looked at the related messages on Stackoverflow and in Google and cannot find anything that can help me. Disclaimer - I am in a corporate environment and I don't have admin rights to my Windows. I tried ng new MyApp, npm install, npm cache clean --force commands and all of them return the same error message:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\npmv\9.3.1\lib\cli.js:48
    throw err
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@npmcli/arborist'
Require stack:
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\npmv\9.3.1\lib\npm.js
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\npmv\9.3.1\lib\cli.js
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\npmv\9.3.1\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\npmv\9.3.1\lib\npm.js:1:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at module.exports (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\npmv\9.3.1\lib\cli.js:82:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\npmv\9.3.1\bin\npm-cli.js:2:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\npmv\\9.3.1\\lib\\npm.js',
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\npmv\\9.3.1\\lib\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\npmv\\9.3.1\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

What can I do to solve this issue? I don't know how to install nodist if I need to re-install that. My ng version returns:
Angular CLI: 15.2.10
Node: 16.13.0
Package Manager: npm 
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1502.10 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         15.2.10 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   15.2.10 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          15.2.10 (cli-only)  


You should try to repair Node installation, if that's possible due to corporate environment.

Tried running this script found on node.js website through Chocolatey, but it gave me an error about 'Installation of Chocolatey to default folder requires Administrative permissions.'

Go to Control Panel --> find Node --> click and select repair.

In Control Panel I found Node.js. When I try Modify, then Repair option it fails eventually with  'The feature you're trying to use is on the network resource that is unavailable. It points to C:\Program Files (x86)\Tanium\Tanium Client\Tools\SoftwareManagement\data\temp\tasks\Deployment_140_task_153\ which I don't have.

You should talk to your system admin :S.
